# Contributor vs participator difference?

Tags: word-usage

Is the word contributor part of participator or completely different words? Or can they be interchangeable in some cases?

Comment: They are different. One can participate without contributing anything (someone attends an event but does nothing), or contribute with participating (someone makes a donation to a cause in which they are not involved).

Comment: @Weather Vane. If I understand correctly your comment,  there's a typo where you mention people non involved: they contribute without partecipating.

Comment: @LucianoPetrillo yes: I meant **without** participating but I am glad the meaning was clear.